# javascript validation code wont work

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm coding a validation script but when i run the code nothing happen except all the text field borders turn red (which is supposed to happen, but it still is red on the condition that there are text in the text field ). here is my code

```
 function frontendvalidation(){
 var emailaddbox = document.getElementById('emailaddbox').value;
 //var emailaddbox = document.forms["signupform"]["emailaddbox"].value;
 var username = document.getElementById('username').value;

 var password = document.getElementById('passwordbox').value;

 var confirmpasswordbox = document.getElementById('confirmpasswordbox').value;

// if our signup fields are  empty then the border will be red
if(username === '' || emailaddbox === '' || password=== '' || confirmpasswordbox=== ''){

     document.getElementById('username').   style.borderColor = "red";
     document.getElementById('emailaddbox').style.borderColor = "red";  
     document.getElementById('passwordbox').style.borderColor = "red";
     document.getElementById('confirmpasswordbox').style.borderColor = "red";

     return false;

 } 

if(username === !'' && username.length => 5) {
   document.getElementById('username').   style.borderColor = "green";

     return true;
 }

 if(emailaddbox === !'' ){

 document.getElementById('emailaddbox').style.borderColor = "green";  

 }

 if (password === ! '' && password.length <=5){

              document.getElementById('passwordbox').style.borderColor = "green";


 }

 if ( password != confirmpasswordbox){
            document.getElementById('confirmpasswordbox').style.borderColor = "red";

 } else if (confirmpasswordbox === password){

             document.getElementById('confirmpasswordbox').style.borderColor = "green";
          return true ;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the conditions `username === !''` to `username !== ''`

The syntax `!''` every is `false`, and if you compare with an string you will obtain every time `false` because you are comparing with `===`, them need to compare with another similar string to obtain a `true`result, in you case `'' === false` then is every time `false`.

I fix your code, and saw that there are many syntax error like `=>`, the correct is `>=`. See the code that i fix.

I think is this that you want.

```js
function frontendvalidation(event){
    var elementEmail = document.getElementById('emailaddbox');
    var elementUserName = document.getElementById('username');
    var elementPassword = document.getElementById('passwordbox');
    var elementConfirmPassword = document.getElementById('confirmpasswordbox');
    var validate = false;

    if (elementUserName.value !== '' && elementUserName.value.length >= 5) {
        elementUserName.style.borderColor = "green";
        validate = validate ? validate : true;
    } else {
     elementUserName.style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    
    if (elementEmail.value !== '') {
      elementEmail.style.borderColor = "green"; 
       validate = validate ? validate : true;
    } else {
      elementEmail.style.borderColor = "red";
    } 
    
    if (elementPassword.value !== '' && elementPassword.value.length <= 5){
        elementPassword.style.borderColor = "green";
        validate = validate ? validate : true;
    } else {
     elementPassword.style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    
    if ( elementConfirmPassword.value !== '' && elementConfirmPassword.value === elementPassword.value){
        elementConfirmPassword.style.borderColor = "green";
        validate = validate ? validate : true;
    } else {
     elementConfirmPassword.style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    
    return validate;
} 

document.getElementById('btnValidator').onclick = frontendvalidation;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="emailaddbox" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="passwordbox" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="confirmpasswordbox" /><br/>
<button id="btnValidator" >Validator</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with:

```
if (password === ! '' && password.length <=5){
    document.getElementById('passwordbox').style.borderColor = "green";
}
```

Try something like this instead:

```
if (password != undefined && password.length > 5){
    document.getElementById('passwordbox').style.borderColor = "green";
}
```

Basically `password === ! ''` is not valid syntax. You're saying something like "password is stictly equal to the inverse of an empty string". Which, with some JavaScript type gymnastics, equates to "password is strictly equal to true".

(Also, it would seem to make more sense to force the password to by longer than 5 characters, not less than or equal to 5 characters)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the syntax errors outlined in other answers, the line checking for blanks in any field is marking all fields as an error if any of them are blank. Also there was a syntax error here: username.length => 5  it should be username.length >= 5

Here is updated working code:

```
function frontendvalidation(){
  var emailaddbox = document.getElementById('emailaddbox').value;
   //var emailaddbox = document.forms["signupform"]["emailaddbox"].value;
  var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('passwordbox').value;
  var confirmpasswordbox = document.getElementById('confirmpasswordbox').value;

  //Default to everything showing an error, and clear the errors as fields are validated.
  document.getElementById('username').style.borderColor = "red";
  document.getElementById('emailaddbox').style.borderColor = "red";  
  document.getElementById('passwordbox').style.borderColor = "red";
  document.getElementById('confirmpasswordbox').style.borderColor = "red";

  // if our signup fields are  empty then the border will be red
  if(username === '' && emailaddbox === '' && password=== '' && confirmpasswordbox=== ''){
       return false;
   } 

  if(username !== '' && username.length >= 5) {
    document.getElementById('username').style.borderColor = "green";
  }

  if (emailaddbox !== '' ){
    document.getElementById('emailaddbox').style.borderColor = "green";  
  }

  if (password !== '' && password.length <=5){
    document.getElementById('passwordbox').style.borderColor = "green";
  }

  if ( password != confirmpasswordbox){
    document.getElementById('confirmpasswordbox').style.borderColor = "red";
  } else if (confirmpasswordbox === password){
    document.getElementById('confirmpasswordbox').style.borderColor = "green";
    return true ;
  }
}
```

Working Codepen: http://codepen.io/nobrien/pen/oxqoeR